# drop-down menu with errors

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'll add the link in the comments to the code I'm with doubt, to facilitate graft and not the question of code. ok?

My problem are a drop-down menu with jquery. When you open the jsFiddle will easily notice when you hover on the first menu item.

And as it stands, he away menu items when I pass the mouse, and do not know how to grow submenu necessary without interfering with `<li>` menu.

Comment: Link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/n5VWn/1/

Comment: I still can't. I'm trying to limit the <li> sub-menu, but not working, jquery always increases the widht of the <li> menu. I've tried to limit the height, put overflow in bg_menu so she does not accompany the slide, but it will.

Comment: Although a jsfiddle link is really nice, don't forget to add the related code to the question for the next questions. The site does not allow jsfiddle-link only questions to be posted for a reason. `;)` Reference: [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: Paste a lot of code seemed like a bad idea, rsrsrsr.

Comment: Completely agree, don't paste you whole site - try to narrow it down to the relevant code. Recreate your problem with as few extras as you can and paste that in the question.

Comment: yes, but I believe it could not reduce much more than that, maybe remove the content, something like that, but I think it would not to remove too much. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
.sub-menu { position:absolute; }
```

So that the sub menus are taken out of the page flow. Their top and left positions are default to where they'd be in the regular page flow, but they will no longer push down the page nor extend their `nav` container.

You will have to style them accordingly after this change. That is, the parent `li`'s `padding` still pushes them to the right while they use the default top/left positions. You may give the sub menus a negative margin, or more cleanly, remove the padding from the `li` and wrap their heading text into an element with padding e.g.:

```
<li class="menu_li show-sub-menu">
    <span>Veículos</span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Estoque</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Veículo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
.menu_li > span, .menu_li > a { padding:0 14px; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5VWn/2/)

---

Also, there are a lot of ready-made dropdown nav menus available out there: http://www.cssreflex.com/2011/11/jquery-css-drop-down-menus.html/